# IIS virtual directory goes to main site

Tags: windows, iis, asp-classic, windows-server-2012, iis-8.5

I have a Windows 2012 Server with IIS8. On it I have a default web site, 
defaultsite.com/

and under that site I have two virtual directory sub-site classic asp applications.
defaultsite.com/Site1
defaultsite.com/Site2

Now site2 works fine, but when I go to defaultsite.com/Site1 my browser (IE11) gets sent to defaultsite.com/

Any idea what setting could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen websites where a 404 error (page not found) redirects to the home page instead of throwing a 404 error. Possibly your home page in defaultsite.com/Site1 is not configured correctly. You can check if your default page is set up correctly and exists.